# How to start a process from an WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf

I would like to run a process from my client `Winforms` application, In my case a client asks a server to create a new process on the server's machine:

```
public void RunEXE()
{
    var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"D:\MyFile.exe")
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    };
    Process proc;

    if ((proc = Process.Start(processInfo)) == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("??");
    }

    proc.WaitForExit();
    int exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
    proc.Close();
}
```

Currently nothing happen even if i try to run this service on my local machine.
Other operation like update, receive string works fine on local and remote machines.

Server app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings />
    <client />
    <services>
      <service name="WCFServiceHosting.MyService">
        <endpoint name="ServiceHttpEndPoint" address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFServiceHosting.IParametersXMLService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint name="ServiceMexEndPoint" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://0.0.0.0:8733/MyService/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand how a WCF call works (by default): the client send a message to the server, on the server, a new instance of the service class is instantiated, the service method is called, and when the call is finished, that instantiated service class is disposed of. So anything that was started during that call will also be disposed of right away. A WCF service method shouldn't be starting other processes or things like that .....

Comment: So how can i start process from this remote machine ?

Comment: Does the application pool have enough rights to start a process?

Comment: I would probably just have the WCF service make an entry into e.g. a database table, which defines what to start (path to exe, parameters etc.), and then have a separate process (e.g. a Windows Service, or a scheduled command line utility) that would check that database table for new entries, and if one is found, execute it.

Comment: Maybe some other solution beside Database ? user @Silvermind: the application is from the client side, the service that i want to start the process have rights